# resolver Angular 6

Tags: typescript, angular5, angular-routing, rxjs

Можно ли в `resolver` Angular 6 получить `router params`?

```
this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params === []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно, метод `resolve` может принимать 2 аргумента:

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<T> | Promise<T> | T;
```

В сервисе, который используется как разрешитель просто объявите аргумент в методе `resolve`:

```
@Injectable()
export class Resolver implements Resolve<any> {
    public resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
        console.log(route.params); // или
        console.log(route.paramMap.get('some-param-name'));
    }
}
```

К тому же так делать нельзя `route.snapshot.params === []`, `params` это ли объект (если вы обращаетесь к свойству инстанса `ActivatedRouteSnapshot`), либо поток (если обращаетесь к свойству инстанса `ActivatedRoute`).